# Getting error message while starting appium

Tags: appium

After start the appium server. I got this message. Kindly tell what went wrong
usage: main.js [-h] [-v] [--shell]

> ```
>            [--localizable-strings-dir LOCALIZABLESTRINGSDIR] [--app APP]
>            [--ipa IPA] [-q] [-U UDID] [-a ADDRESS] [-p PORT]
>            [-bp BOOTSTRAPPORT] [-k] [-r BACKENDRETRIES]
>            [--session-override] [--full-reset] [--no-reset] [-l]
>            [-lt LAUNCHTIMEOUT] [-g LOG]
>            [--log-level {debug,info,warn,error}] [--log-timestamp]
>            [--log-no-colors] [-G WEBHOOK] [--native-instruments-lib]
>            [--app-pkg ANDROIDPACKAGE] [--app-activity ANDROIDACTIVITY]
>            [--app-wait-package ANDROIDWAITPACKAGE]
>            [--app-wait-activity ANDROIDWAITACTIVITY]
>            [--android-coverage ANDROIDCOVERAGE] [--avd AVD]
>            [--avd-args AVDARGS]
>            [--device-ready-timeout ANDROIDDEVICEREADYTIMEOUT] [--safari]
>            [--device-name DEVICENAME] [--platform-name PLATFORMNAME]
>            [--platform-version PLATFORMVERSION]
> ```
>
> main.js: error: argument "--app": Expected one argument. null

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `--app` when you start the server but you're not giving it an app to point to.

Try `appium --app /path/to/app` (replace that with the real path to the `.app` you're trying to automate)

Answer (score 0):

I know its very old question, but still would like to know the 'Application Path' (.apk file path) you set on Appium server.
I was facing the same problem, so would like to add my solution which solved my problem, may be it help the next reader.

Make sure that the path doesn't have any blank/white spaces in it. If so then copy your .apk in such folder which do not have spaces in it.